# Is it true that $z^{w+1}=z^w\cdot z$ where $z,w\in \Bbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation, branch-cuts, branch-points

Is it true that $z^{w+1}=z^w\cdot z$ where $z,w\in \Bbb{C}$? The original question didn't state whether $w\in \Bbb{C}$, but I guess that would be the case, and it is a more inclusive approach. I arrived at $e^{(w+1)\log(z)}=e^{w\log(z)}\cdot e^{\log(z)}$, and it seems just about it. I don't even refer to the existence of the branches above, and it doesn't seem like I need to. I just don't see the point in requiring such a short process. Could you contribute your perspective?

Comment: What does "$\log z$" mean in your simple solution?

Comment: It is $\ln |z|+i\text{Arg}(z)+2\pi i k$ but it doesn't seem to get me any further...

Comment: Should the two sides be functions of $z$ with fixed $w$, functions of $w$ with fixed $z$, or functions of both, $w$ and $z$?

Comment: Do you ask me as a hint or due to a lack of basic information? The two were just given as is.(I am not native but it seems like a hint)

Comment: If it is a hint I would like to ponder...

Comment: It was a request for clarification. The answer is mostly "if you use the same logarithm of $z$ on both sides, then yes", but the details of what "mostly" means depend on the scenario.

Comment: I am afraid I caught no scenario... It was simply put there as a part of a list of statement I am to prove or disprove... In that list it was also asked whether $\log({1\over z})=-\log(z)$, $\log(z^2)=2\log(z)$ and etc...

Comment: I would assume it targets a more broad set of scenarios so that one understands what they might be dealing with when handling a complex expression...

Answer (score 0):

To provide an answer:

Assuming a principal branch for $\log$ is chosen so that $\log(z)$ is not multivalued, then this is indeed true and the proof is as short as you say. Of course, with multivalued $\log$ we can get different results on each side if we take different values for $\log(z)$ on each side, supposing $w$ is not an integer.

Comment: Of course it is important that the exponent $1$ here is an integer.  It may fail that $z^{1/2+1/2}=z^{1/2}\;z^{1/2}$ when we use the principal value.